# No Page Layouts show in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, white-screen

I've been working with magento for a long time. I've done all the basics.  I'm also to the point i'm stepping through code using `xdebug + phpstorm` and STILL can't figure it out.

None of the default templates will show on my site. In admin, when i edit a page, and click the dropdown for layouts, its just empty. I've ripped every single  customized part / module out, and i've also deleted the enterprise / base themes and re-copied them over in case i had done something stupid in the past for a fix. My `/app/code/local` directory is GONE, and i've deleted community, and all the modules in `/etc` related to them. I've chosen enterprise and even base just to get something to happen at all.  All i can get is no layouts in the backend, and the white screen of death on the front.  No logs entries in system, php, nginx, anything.

All caches are disabled, and i'm still clearing and deleting the cache folder.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why magento can't get the layouts out of enterprise / base.

Answer (score 1):

Try keeping this peace of code in your index.php file

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR);
register_shutdown_function("fatal_handler");
function fatal_handler() {
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo("<pre>");
    print_r($error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some dork changed the Mage_Page.xml code pool to local.